# React router with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router` and `react-router-dom` with Typescript to build an application. I have defined my routes in this way (`routes.tsx`):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignUp from '../routes/signup';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const Routes: React.StatelessComponent<{}> = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default Router;
```

I have a main `App` component that renders this `Routes` component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Routes from './routes';

const App: React.StatelessComponent<{}> = () => (
  <Routes />
);

export default App;
```

The compiler throws this error

```
(5,4): Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouterProps>'.
  Property 'history' is missing in type '{}'.
```

I am new to TS so I am not sure what exactly is going on.

Comment: I think `export default Router;` should be `export default Routes;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript, like most languages, expects a type specifier between `< >` markers on a class. This is indicating that the class is a generic that expects further definition.

I am not able to find specific documentation on this class that you're using, but I would guess something like this might help get you to the right place:

```
const App: React.StatelessComponent<RouterProps> = () => (
  <Routes />
);
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but it says `RouterProps` is not generic.